# Error Weld when starting WildFly 8 with Spring 3

Tags: spring, jboss, cdi, weld, wildfly

When I update my application, from Jboss-as 7.1.1.Final to Wildfly 8.0.0.Alpha4, there was an error that I can not fix.

I think this error is related to the new version of org.jboss.weld modules, which were 1.1 in the previous version of JBoss, and now, in this new version of WildFly is 2.0.3. As is in "JBOSS_HOME\modules\org\jboss\weld\[...]\main"

```
19:57:20,955 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."cineserver.war".component."org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest".WeldInstantiator: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."cineserver.war".component."org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1900) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionPointFactory.getParameterInjectionPoints(InjectionPointFactory.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.AbstractCallableInjectionPoint.<init>(AbstractCallableInjectionPoint.java:49)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.<init>(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionPointFactory.createConstructorInjectionPoint(InjectionPointFactory.java:173)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInstantiator.<init>(DefaultInstantiator.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.initInstantiator(BasicInjectionTarget.java:144)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.<init>(BasicInjectionTarget.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.NonContextualComponentInjectionTarget.<init>(NonContextualComponentInjectionTarget.java:48)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.NonContextualComponentInjectionTarget.<init>(NonContextualComponentInjectionTarget.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldComponentService.start(WeldComponentService.java:129)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1944) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1877) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
    ... 3 more

19:57:21,018 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "cineserver.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"cineserver.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest\".WeldInstantiator" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"cineserver.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest\".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
19:57:21,018 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "cineserver.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"cineserver.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest\".WeldInstantiator" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"cineserver.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest\".WeldInstantiator: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Looks like a bug in weld.

Comment: I also suspect that, @AdrianMitev. For those who wish to follow, I opened a Jira on Weld --> issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1489 and --> community.jboss.org/message/834743#834743

Comment: ops, now in link format: http://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-1489 and http://community.jboss.org/message/834743#834743

Answer (score 0):

This was bug in weld and fix should be available in recently released WildFly 8 Beta1.